# order letters for each element in a vector based on another vector in r

Tags: r

I have a vector looks like:

```
SNP <- c("A/G","A/C","A/C","T/C","A/G","A/C","T/G","T/C","A/C","T/G")
```

second vector (REF) is a vector of one of two letters for each elements in "SNP":

```
REF <- c("G","C","A","C","A","A","T","T","C","T")
```

I would like to put any letter of each element in the vector "SNP" in the front if matching the corresponding element (letter) in vector "REF". 
The expected result is:

```
SNP <- c("G/A","C/A","A/C","C/T","A/G","A/C","T/G","T/C","C/A","T/G")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
mapply(function(x,y) paste(y,setdiff(x,y),sep="/"),
         strsplit(SNP,"/",fixed=TRUE),REF) 
#[1] "G/A" "C/A" "A/C" "C/T" "A/G" "A/C" "T/G" "T/C" "C/A" "T/G"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way

```
m1 <- t(matrix(scan(text=SNP, sep='/', what='', 
                   quiet=TRUE),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
i1 <- t(t(m1)==REF)
paste(m1[i1], m1[!i1], sep='/')
#[1] "G/A" "C/A" "A/C" "C/T" "A/G" "A/C" "T/G" "T/C" "C/A" "T/G"
```